# Design Pattern for Winform .NET to ASP.NET project

Tags: .net, asp.net, winforms, design-patterns, datasource

What is currently the most **widely used** and accepted **design pattern** for developing **.NET** applications with a **Windows** and **Web** User Interface?

An example of this could be an application that retrieves data from a 3rd party source (such as an RSS feed) with the following user interfaces:

- WinForms UI that caches some data locally (xml)
- ASP.NET Web UI that caches data on a server (SQL)

> My thoughts are **MVC**, **MVP** or
>   **MVVM**. I am looking for a modern pattern that utilizes or applies to specific
>   .NET features (such as Data Binding,
>   LINQ and IProviders).

Comment: If your using MVC look at ASP.NET MVC instead of ASP.NET

Comment: I know ASP.NET has a built in MVC framework, I just thought MVC was only applicable to web applications.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a different framework from ASP.NET, the MVC pattern is applicable to web forms, but there is no framework for it.

Answer (score 2):

MVC is a great pattern.  It helps create separation of concerns within your architecture.  Above all - make sure your code is modular, easy to read, testable and maintainable.  These are all elements of a good MVC design.

Comment: I know ASP.NET has the MVC framework built in, but there is no MVC built in for WinForms. I thought this may be because it is not suitable for WinForms, as some forms may require multiple views.

Comment: In other words - isn't MVC a purely web design pattern?

Answer (score 0):

MVC or MVP would work well, not too sure that MVVM works on the web (can anyone clarify)?

You will need to have a service layer so you can share business logic and data layers.

More about the service layer:

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am leaning towards using MVP as my presentation layer pattern for both the Web and Windows Client.